# Replacing characters in dynamically loaded and navigated content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a JavaScript script that replaces certain characters (in this case, Mandaic characters) with corresponding characters from another alphabet (Hebrew characters) within a webpage. The web pages I am working with contain both static and dynamically loaded content, as well as links that lead to other pages where the replacement should also occur. I've tried several approaches to handle character replacement across different scenarios. However, I'm still facing issues where the script doesn't consistently replace characters when navigating to a new page using links. I'm looking for advice or alternative solutions to handle character replacement in all cases effectively.

To keep the Stack Overflow question concise, I have included the relevant code for replacing characters at the end of the question. Additionally, the steps to navigate to a dynamically updated page with text on the website are provided below the code.

## Initial Solution:

The initial script provided used a simple approach of replacing Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters for specified HTML tags (such as  and  tags). The script worked when directly accessing a page with a detailed address but didn't work when clicking on links or when the page content was dynamically updated.

```js
function replaceMandaicCharacters() { /* ... */ }

replaceMandaicCharacters();
```

## Option 1: MutationObserver

To handle dynamic content updates, a MutationObserver was added to observe changes in the page's content. However, this approach didn't work as expected. When clicking on a link, the script didn't replace Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters on the new page.

```js
function replaceMandaicCharacters() { /* ... */ }

replaceMandaicCharacters();

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      replaceMandaicCharacters();
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

## Option 2: setInterval and hash comparison#

In this approach, the script used setInterval to periodically check for content changes by comparing the hash of the current content with the hash of the previously processed content. If the hashes were different, the script called the replaceMandaicCharacters function to update the text. While this method worked for some cases, it still didn't consistently replace Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters when clicking on links.

```js
function replaceMandaicCharacters() { /* ... */ }

flet lastContentHash = '';

function checkForContentChanges() {
  const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
  if (!iframe || !iframe.contentDocument) {
    return;
  }

  const currentContent = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
  const currentHash = hashString(currentContent);

  if (currentHash !== lastContentHash) {
    replaceMandaicCharacters(iframe.contentDocument);
    addLinkEventListeners(); // Add this line
    lastContentHash = currentHash;
  }
}

function hashString(str) {
  let hash = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = (hash << 5) - hash + charCode;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32-bit integer
  }
  return hash;
}

setInterval(checkForContentChanges, 1000);
```

## Option 3: Click event listeners

The next approach involved adding a click event listener to all  tags in the document. When a link was clicked, the script called the replaceMandaicCharacters function after a short delay (500ms) to allow the new content to load. This approach was also supposed to handle dynamic content updates. However, the script still didn't work as expected when clicking on links.

```js
function replaceMandaicCharacters() { /* ... */ }

function addClickListeners() {
  const links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (const link of links) {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      setTimeout(replaceMandaicCharacters, 500);
    });
  }
}

replaceMandaicCharacters();
addClickListeners();
```

## Summary

Despite trying different approaches, the script has not yet consistently replaced Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters when navigating between pages or when content is dynamically updated. The script works when directly accessing a page with a detailed address but not when clicking on links.

## Replacement code

```
function replaceMandaicCharacters(contentDocument) {
  const mandaicLetters =
    "\u{0840}\u{0841}\u{0842}\u{0843}\u{0844}\u{0845}\u{0846}\u{0847}\u{0848}\u{0849}\u{084A}\u{084B}\u{084C}\u{084D}\u{084E}\u{084F}\u{0850}\u{0851}\u{0852}\u{0853}\u{0854}\u{0855}";
  const hebrewLetters = "אבגדחוזהטיכלמנסעפצקרשת";
  const targetTags = ["b", "a"];

  const replaceText = (originalText) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${mandaicLetters}\u{0856}\u{0857}]`, "g");
    return originalText.replace(regex, (match) => {
      if (match === "\u{0856}") {
        return "\u{05D3}\u{05B7}";
      } else if (match === "\u{0857}") {
        return "\u{05DB}\u{05D9}";
      }
      const index = mandaicLetters.indexOf(match);
      return hebrewLetters.charAt(index);
    });
  };

  for (const tag of targetTags) {
    const elements = contentDocument.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (const element of elements) {
      if (tag === "a") {
        const originalText = element.childNodes[0]?.nodeValue || "";
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = newText;
        }
      } else {
        const originalText = element.textContent;
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.textContent = newText;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const textNodes = contentDocument.evaluate(
    "//text()",
    contentDocument,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < textNodes.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const textNode = textNodes.snapshotItem(i);
    const originalText = textNode.textContent;
    const newText = replaceText(originalText);
    if (newText !== originalText) {
      textNode.textContent = newText;
    }
  }
}
```

## How do you get to a site where it doesn't work?

In the provided example, the issue of the script not working properly is observed when navigating through a series of pages that require user interaction. To replicate the issue, follow these steps:

1. Visit https://cal.huc.edu/.
2. Click on "Search the CAL lexical and textual databases" in the side menu.
3. On the page that opens, click
   on "Text Browse."
4. On the "Text Browse" page, select "Babylonian
   Aramaic" and click "Submit."
5. In the search results, scroll down to
   the item with ID 74401 (and onwards).
6. Click on the item to view the
   list of pages in the book.
7. Click on any page to navigate to a page
   with a Latin transcription. Notice that the address bar still shows
   https://cal.huc.edu/. On the transcription page, click the "View in
   Mandaic" option.

After following these steps, the script does not work as expected on the dynamically loaded content. The Mandaic characters are not consistently replaced with their corresponding Hebrew characters.

**Before and after illustration:**

To help visualize the issue, I've included two images illustrating the problem.

*Before image* - This image shows the page with Mandaic text before applying the script. The Mandaic characters are visible, and the text needs to be replaced with the corresponding Hebrew characters.

[image: Before image]

*After image* - This image demonstrates the desired outcome after applying the script. The Mandaic characters have been replaced with the corresponding Hebrew characters. It works great if you access the page directly using this [link](https://cal.huc.edu/manget_a_chapter.php?file=74401&sub=11&cset=M), but it doesn't work if you navigate to the page through the website.

[image]

Comment: @mplungjan What you see is Mandaic, the code in JS replace it to Hebrew letters.

Comment: @mplungjan before & after images added.
My apologies for any confusion. What I meant is that the characters change consistently based on how you arrive at the page. In some cases (direct link), you will see the Hebrew characters, while in others (website navigation), you won't.

Comment: @mplungjan
The most naive activation for the replacement function is:
```// Call replaceMandaicCharacters() whenever the DOM is updated
const observer = new MutationObserver(replaceMandaicCharacters);
observer.observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });```
But it doesn't support the navigation case.

Comment: @mplungjan I apologize if my instructions were unclear. I want to convert the Mandaic characters to Hebrew whenever the page loads or updates with new content. The conversion works correctly when arriving at the page directly through a specific link, but it doesn't work when navigating the website to reach the same page.

To clarify, the direct link should show Hebrew characters if the provided script is executed. If you are not seeing the Hebrew characters after following the steps I provided and script execution, please let me know, and I'll try to further clarify or troubleshoot the issue

Comment: This is the repository containing only one JavaScript file with the provided content:
https://github.com/yanirmr/mandaic-to-hebrew-extension

Comment: @mplungjan You don't see Hebrew because the original page includes only Mandaic, if you apply the code, all the characters will be converted into Hebrew.

Comment: @mplungjan. Thank you for pointing out the issue with the generated HTML.
My code is responsible for replacing Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters in the text. However, I am not directly modifying the HTML structure or adding any new elements. Can you please provide an example of where the invalid `<span>` tag appears, so I can further investigate the issue and see if my code is causing it? Your input is appreciated.

Comment: My intention is for the character replacement to occur automatically when the page is loaded, without requiring the user to click any buttons. The issue I'm facing is that the character replacement works when accessing the page directly using a specific link, but it doesn't work when navigating to the page through the website. I'm trying to find a solution to ensure that the character replacement happens consistently, regardless of how the user arrives at the page, as long as the code is running in the background. I hope this clarifies my goal.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. While your code provides an interesting approach to detecting and logging clicked words that contain UTF-8 characters, it doesn't directly address the current task of automatically replacing Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters when the page loads. Our goal is to have the replacement occur automatically in the background without any user interaction, such as clicking on words. Nonetheless, I appreciate your input, and it could be helpful for implementing a different feature in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your input on the website's HTML structure. I appreciate your concern, but I am not the owner of the website and cannot make changes to its structure. My task is focused on finding a solution to automatically replace Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters when the page loads, despite the existing issues with the website's structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the site. Click ctrl-d to make a bookmark
2. Edit the bookmark
3. Paste this into the location in the bookmark

```
javascript:(function replaceMandaicCharacters() {
  const contentDocument = window.frames[1].document;
  const mandaicLetters =
    "\u{0840}\u{0841}\u{0842}\u{0843}\u{0844}\u{0845}\u{0846}\u{0847}\u{0848}\u{0849}\u{084A}\u{084B}\u{084C}\u{084D}\u{084E}\u{084F}\u{0850}\u{0851}\u{0852}\u{0853}\u{0854}\u{0855}";
  const hebrewLetters = "אבגדחוזהטיכלמנסעפצקרשת";
  const targetTags = ["b", "a"];

  const replaceText = (originalText) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${mandaicLetters}\u{0856}\u{0857}]`, "g");
    return originalText.replace(regex, (match) => {
      if (match === "\u{0856}") {
        return "\u{05D3}\u{05B7}";
      } else if (match === "\u{0857}") {
        return "\u{05DB}\u{05D9}";
      }
      const index = mandaicLetters.indexOf(match);
      return hebrewLetters.charAt(index);
    });
  };

  for (const tag of targetTags) {
    const elements = contentDocument.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (const element of elements) {
      if (tag === "a") {
        const originalText = element.childNodes[0]?.nodeValue || "";
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = newText;
        }
      } else {
        const originalText = element.textContent;
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.textContent = newText;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const textNodes = contentDocument.evaluate(
    "//text()",
    contentDocument,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < textNodes.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const textNode = textNodes.snapshotItem(i);
    const originalText = textNode.textContent;
    const newText = replaceText(originalText);
    if (newText !== originalText) {
      textNode.textContent = newText;
    }
  }
})()(function replaceMandaicCharacters() {
  const contentDocument = window.frames[1].document;
  const mandaicLetters =
    "\u{0840}\u{0841}\u{0842}\u{0843}\u{0844}\u{0845}\u{0846}\u{0847}\u{0848}\u{0849}\u{084A}\u{084B}\u{084C}\u{084D}\u{084E}\u{084F}\u{0850}\u{0851}\u{0852}\u{0853}\u{0854}\u{0855}";
  const hebrewLetters = "אבגדחוזהטיכלמנסעפצקרשת";
  const targetTags = ["b", "a"];

  const replaceText = (originalText) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${mandaicLetters}\u{0856}\u{0857}]`, "g");
    return originalText.replace(regex, (match) => {
      if (match === "\u{0856}") {
        return "\u{05D3}\u{05B7}";
      } else if (match === "\u{0857}") {
        return "\u{05DB}\u{05D9}";
      }
      const index = mandaicLetters.indexOf(match);
      return hebrewLetters.charAt(index);
    });
  };

  for (const tag of targetTags) {
    const elements = contentDocument.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (const element of elements) {
      if (tag === "a") {
        const originalText = element.childNodes[0]?.nodeValue || "";
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = newText;
        }
      } else {
        const originalText = element.textContent;
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.textContent = newText;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const textNodes = contentDocument.evaluate(
    "//text()",
    contentDocument,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < textNodes.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const textNode = textNodes.snapshotItem(i);
    const originalText = textNode.textContent;
    const newText = replaceText(originalText);
    if (newText !== originalText) {
      textNode.textContent = newText;
    }
  }
})()(function replaceMandaicCharacters() {
  const contentDocument = window.frames[1].document;
  const mandaicLetters =
    "\u{0840}\u{0841}\u{0842}\u{0843}\u{0844}\u{0845}\u{0846}\u{0847}\u{0848}\u{0849}\u{084A}\u{084B}\u{084C}\u{084D}\u{084E}\u{084F}\u{0850}\u{0851}\u{0852}\u{0853}\u{0854}\u{0855}";
  const hebrewLetters = "אבגדחוזהטיכלמנסעפצקרשת";
  const targetTags = ["b", "a"];

  const replaceText = (originalText) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${mandaicLetters}\u{0856}\u{0857}]`, "g");
    return originalText.replace(regex, (match) => {
      if (match === "\u{0856}") {
        return "\u{05D3}\u{05B7}";
      } else if (match === "\u{0857}") {
        return "\u{05DB}\u{05D9}";
      }
      const index = mandaicLetters.indexOf(match);
      return hebrewLetters.charAt(index);
    });
  };

  for (const tag of targetTags) {
    const elements = contentDocument.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (const element of elements) {
      if (tag === "a") {
        const originalText = element.childNodes[0]?.nodeValue || "";
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = newText;
        }
      } else {
        const originalText = element.textContent;
        const newText = replaceText(originalText);
        if (newText !== originalText) {
          element.textContent = newText;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const textNodes = contentDocument.evaluate(
    "//text()",
    contentDocument,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < textNodes.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const textNode = textNodes.snapshotItem(i);
    const originalText = textNode.textContent;
    const newText = replaceText(originalText);
    if (newText !== originalText) {
      textNode.textContent = newText;
    }
  }
})()
```

Now you can use that bookmarklet on pages with Mandaleic texts in a frameset where the second frame has the text.

I wrapped the code in

`javascript:( ........... )()`

and changed to `const contentDocument = window.frames[1].document;`